# How i decompress zip files in tests from cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, compression, cypress, unzip

Hi I need someone who can write an automation test using cypress/Javascript to integrate with a Cypress automation test. The requirement is to unzip a downloaded zip file located in cypress/downloads/sample.zip using a cypress automation test. After unzipping it through the automation test I should be able to access the unzipped files which are available inside the downloads folder.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have something that can help you.
I created a plugin using node.js decompress library.

I'll upload my project on git. just follow the instructions on read me.

https://github.com/MMCampos1703/unzipCypress

Comment: Thanks I'll try

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).